# Binding an image in a datatemplate

Tags: wpf, mvvm, binding, datacontext

I'm trying to add a menu to my application, I'd like that my menu header is the currently connected user's picture.

My issue is that every binding works except the one for the image, from what I've understood on the net the DataTemplate I use to replace the menu header by a picture doesn't have access to it's parent Datacontext. I tried to use some stuff like relative source and other tricks but with no luck (certainely related to the fact that I'm new in mvvm and I obviously still have a lot to learn :) )

Here's the code I'm using :

```
<Grid DataContext="{Binding User}">
    <DockPanel>
        <Label Content="{Binding Strings.Hello, Source={StaticResource StringLocalizer} }" VerticalAlignment="Center" Padding="0,0,5,0" FontFamily="{DynamicResource Font_Normal}" FontSize="15" Foreground="White"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayName, TargetNullValue='Guest', FallbackValue='Guest'}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontFamily="{DynamicResource Font_Normal}" FontSize="15" Foreground="White"/>


        <Menu Name="LogonMenu" Margin="10,0,0,0" DataContext="{Binding User}">
            <MenuItem >
                <MenuItem.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <!--<Image Source="{Binding Datacontext.Image,RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Application}}, Converter={StaticResource ImageConverter}, FallbackValue={StaticResource DefaultUserIcon}}"/>-->
                        <Image DataContext="{Binding User}" Source="{Binding Path=Image, Converter={StaticResource ImageConverter}, FallbackValue={StaticResource DefaultUserIcon},Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </MenuItem.HeaderTemplate>

                <MenuItem Header="{Binding Strings.SignIn, Source={StaticResource StringLocalizer}}" Width="150" Margin="10,0,0,0" IsEnabled="{Binding Connected, Converter={StaticResource BoolInverterConverter}}" Visibility="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self},Path=IsEnabled, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}" Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window},Path=DataContext.SignInCommand}"/>
                <MenuItem Header="{Binding Strings.SignOut, Source={StaticResource StringLocalizer}}" Margin="10,0,0,0" IsEnabled="{Binding Connected}" Visibility="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self},Path=IsEnabled, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}" Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window},Path=DataContext.SignOutCommand}"/>
                <MenuItem Header="{Binding Strings.UserInformation, Source={StaticResource StringLocalizer}}" Margin="10,0,0,0" IsEnabled="{Binding Connected}" Visibility="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self},Path=IsEnabled, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
            </MenuItem>
        </Menu>
    </DockPanel>
</Grid>
```

In my case the image always shows the fallback picture, if someone could help me finding a way to have my user's picture it would be great.

Comment: `<Image Source="{Binding Image}">` should be sufficient, provided that `Image` is a public property of type string, Uri or ImageSource (or a type derived from ImageSource). It's not necessary to set the DataContext again, or to have a binding converter. Setting Mode=TwoWay makes no sense at all.

Comment: thanks for the answer but even if I change my image definition this way it's not working. If I copy paste my image in the dockpanel outside of my menu the image the correctly appears.

Comment: Do not set `DataContext="{Binding User}"` at all, or at least not more than one time. Each time you do it you set the new DataContext to a property User in the current DataContext, i.e. User.User.User if you do it three times. The DataContext is inherited from parent to child elements, so set it only once at some top level control, e.g. the main window.

Comment: Hi, solved it by removing the datatemplate and by defining my header this way :  <MenuItem.Header>
                        <Image Source="{Binding Image, Converter={StaticResource ImageConverter}, FallbackValue={StaticResource DefaultUserIcon}}"/>
                    </MenuItem.Header>